# SOIL, problems with NPOT textures

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I can load **725x483** jpg texture but not **725x544**

the code:

```
texId = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(fileName, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, 
                              SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, 0);
```

I got error:
`Access violation reading location 0x06851002` - VS2012 express

I debugged SOIL a bit and it seems that the error comes just after we call glTexImage2D (in the SOIL library).

When I add `SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAP` to the loading code it works fine.

This error was on AMD (5570) and Intel (HD 4000) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but I think it is worth to mention the solution:

- use proper `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`, by default it is 4, but when I changed it to 1 it worked!
- or change data format from `SOIL_LOAD_AUTO` to `SOIL_RGBA`. `AUTO` means original texture format and for jpg images it is RGB, so it can be problematic when unpack alignment is 4.

with `SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAP` soil actually rescales image to POT and that way there are no problems with unpack alignment size.